# Jmeter plugin generates HTML report with some data missing

Tags: plugins, jmeter, test-plan

I have a test plan to create an output CSV file with a view result tree, I have implemented a listener plugin that uses the data from the output CSV file to generate an HTML report, I noticed some data missing from the report, how do I make sure all the data written in CSV file before running the plugin?

I tried to add a flag Http request to check if this value exists in csv file

Answer (score 0):

You can control the contents of the [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) by manipulating [JMeter Properties](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization) which are responsible for the [Results File Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config).

It is also possible to add more columns with custom values of JMeter Variables if you declare them as [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables)